How do I unzip a password protected zip file using Python inside ADLS
Below is the code.
from zipfile import ZipFile 

file_name = "XYZ.zip"

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip: 
    zip.printdir()
    print('Extracting all the files now...') 
    zip.extractall(pwd=b'123123$SADMK6%002#')
    print('Done!')

It is giving "FileNotFoundError" error. Also, I can read other csv files inside ADLS using abfss path without providing accesskey of storage account.

How you are reading other files? using open or pandas read csv?

are you using databricks?

I am using synapse notebook. @jaya

provide pwd field while doing extractall

Is below solution helpfull? @Govind Gupta

csv files are read using abfss path because you are using pandas to read them and pandas uses fsspec and adlfs library which connects to azure storage account using credentials you given.
You did not provided any access key it still worked because it used you default credentials, and with the same you can read zip file like below.
from fsspec.implementations.zip import  ZipFileSystem

strg_opt={'account_name': "jadls", 'anon': False}
tmp = ZipFileSystem(fo="abfs://data/zips/apache-maven-3.9.9-bin.zip",target_options=strg_opt)
tmp.zip.extractall(path="./maven")

Here, the path format should be
'abfs://{CONTAINER}/{FOLDER}/file_name'

refer this for more information.
Output:
In storage account

and extracted in local

If you are using Databricks environment, then mount your storage account using dbutils.fs.mount() and use your initial code on that mount path.
